# Многорукий бандит. Нейронная сеть на pyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, pytorch

Пытаюсь написать решение задачи о многоруком бандите (учусь писать алгоритмы reinforcement learning, начиная с простейшего), используя pyTorch. Есть [статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/newprolab/blog/343834/), но в ней автор использует TenzorFlow, с которым я не знаком. Возникли сложности: как должна выглядеть нейронка и что принимать на вход. Есть вот такой код из статьи:

Функция бандита:

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

bandits = [0.2,0,-0.2,-5]
num_bandits = len(bandits)
def pullBandit(bandit):
    #Сгенерировать случайное число
    result = np.random.randn(1)
    if result > bandit:
        #Выигрыш
        return 1
    else:
        #Проигрыш
        return -1
```

Параметры нейронки

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()

#Эти 2 строчки создают feed-forward часть нейросети. Здесь и происходит выбор действия.
weights = tf.Variable(tf.ones([num_bandits]))
chosen_action = tf.argmax(weights,0)

#Следующие 6 строчек устанавливают процедуру обучения. Нейросеть принимает на вход действие и его результат, чтобы оценить функцию потерь и обновить веса сети.
reward_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[1],dtype=tf.float32)
action_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[1],dtype=tf.int32)
responsible_weight = tf.slice(weights,action_holder,[1])
loss = -(tf.log(responsible_weight)*reward_holder)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
update = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Само обучение:

```py
total_episodes = 1000 #Количество итераций обучения
total_reward = np.zeros(num_bandits) #Изначальный выигрыш всех бандитов равен 0
e = 0.1 #Вероятность случайного выбора
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#Запускаем граф tensorflow
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    i = 0
    while i < total_episodes:

        #Выбираем действие либо случайно либо на основе нейросети
        if np.random.rand(1) < e:
            action = np.random.randint(num_bandits)
        else:
            action = sess.run(chosen_action)
        #Получаем результат игры, выбрав одного из бандитов
        reward = pullBandit(bandits[action]) 

        #Обновляем веса
        _,resp,ww = sess.run([update,responsible_weight,weights], 
                      feed_dict={reward_holder:[reward],action_holder:[action]})

        #Обновляем общий выигрыш каждого бандита
        total_reward[action] += reward
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print("Общий выигрыш бандитов сейчас равен " + str(num_bandits) + 
            " bandits: " + str(total_reward))
        i+=1
print("Агент думает, что бандит №" + str(np.argmax(ww)+1) + " идеален...")
if np.argmax(ww) == np.argmax(-np.array(bandits)):
    print("...и он прав!")
else:
    print("...и он не прав!")
```

Как это будет выглядеть на pyTorch? Я попробовал написать нейронку с одним линейным преобразованием и активацией, основанной на argmax, но у меня ничего не получилось.

Поясню: мне понятен весь код, за исключением того, что происходит в нейросети: что мы подаем ей на вход, какие преобразования выходят внутри и что она выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта ссылка может оказаться очень полезной для тех, кто, как и я, делает первые шаги в reinforcement learning. [Статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/hsespb/blog/444428/)